# ActionBar overlay with GridView padding or custom GridView to show entire first image?

Tags: android, gridview, android-actionbar, customization, padding

I have an activity with a GridView inside it. The ActionBar is set to overlay mode.

Right now, you can only see half of the first image because the ActionBar cuts it in half.

How do I add padding to the interior of the GridView so that it initializes in such a way that you can see the entire first image? Or is there another way? For example, how would I go about extending GridView to create one that has a built-in configurable, dynamic gap at the front?

[image: example]

**example** (although ListView instead of GridView): reddit is fun app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andrewshu.android.reddit

**edit:** I'm *hiding the ActionBar* whenever the user scrolls down at a certain rate or past a certain level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` in your Activity or Fragment to determine the number of columns your `GridView` will display (presuming it varies based on screen size and orientation), then use that number in your `Adapter` implementation. In `getView()`, if `position` is less than the number of columns, return an empty view whose height matches the Action Bar, otherwise bind your data as you would normally.

There is an excellent example that does exactly what you want in Google's "Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently" sample application: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html

Here is the relevant source code:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/training/bitmapfun/src/com/example/android/bitmapfun/ui/ImageGridFragment.java

Comment: Dead link.  New link seems to be https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/2e5555e/samples/training/bitmapfun/src/com/example/android/bitmapfun/ui/ImageGridFragment.java

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"` to the parent of your `GridView`, or the `GridView` itself if it doesn't have one.

This will push your layout down so that it rests below the `ActionBar`.

**Edit**

You may want to conside using a `ListView` instead of a `GridView`. Reason being, you can easily achieve that effect by creating a fake header and then calling [`ListView.addHeaderView`](http://goo.gl/k0Vi5). You can't do the same with a `GridView`. What you're talking about can definitely be done with a `GridView`, but it will require you to subclass it and modify it quite a bit.

**Header**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want. That pushes the entire GridView down. The images are no longer capable of reaching the top of the screen.

note: I'm hiding the ActionBar whenever the user scrolls down at a certain rate or past a certain level.

Comment: By far the easiest to implement from my problem, I can see where it wasn't what the OP wanted though.

Answer (score 3):

Having ActionBar in overlay mode, the following works for me:

```
<GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:columnWidth="120dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/gridLibrary" />
```

The most important lines here are: **android:paddingTop** and **android:clipToPadding**.
In my application, when I open an activity with the gridview above, the first row is fully visible. Then, when I scroll down, the ActionBar hides and the gridview fills up all the screen.